# How do I make sure my HTML login page has the same layout in portrait and landscape in my iPad webview?

Tags: css, html

I have created a login page for iPad in HTML5 which contains one image, Userid, Password and a logout image.

When I open this page in iPad in portrait mode, all its contents moves on left side but in landscape mode it occupies the correct position.

Please someone suggest me how to adjust my HTML page in both landscape and portrait mode.   ![ login page![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We will need to see your HTML and CSS code if we’re going to figure out what the problem is. We’ll also need to know what the correct position is: you’ve only said that “the left” isn’t the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to scroll you content on page you can try `html {position:fixed;}`

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS orientation media queries,  `@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {}` and `@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {}`

For more info visit [How to use CSS3 Orientation Media Queries](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/)